# std::vector as raw array

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

Is it safe to get address of first element in `std::vector` and use it like raw array? Is data aligned continously? What c++ standard says (`c++98` vs `c++11`)? Is it a common practice by the way?

I have some array which size may vary and function which takes pointer and number of elements as argument. It would be great to manage data with `std::vector` and use it with `my_func` at same time.

```
std::vector<int> my_vector;
void my_func(int* int_ptr, int num_ints);
// ..
my_func(&my_vector[0], my_vector.size());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11 (and C++03 for that matter) **guarantees** that the data in `std::vector` are contiguous. This means, that in your case, `&my_vector[0]` can be thought of as the pointer to the zeroth element of that array and normal pointer arithmetic can be used to access the other elements. It's preferred to use `my_vector.data()` to recover the pointer to the zeroth element.

C++98 *almost guarantees* it.

Note that it's **not** true for `std::vector<bool>` for any of the C++ standards. This is because `std::vector<bool>` is implemented as a particular specialisation.

Comment: "almost"? Can you add a quote?

Comment: To fill in the blank, C++03 changed it to be guaranteed from C++98.

Comment: could you link the reference? :)

Comment: In c++11, use the much cleaner `data()` member, that syntax is horrid.. :)

Comment: @Theolodis: the link is in the dupe

Comment: @Nim: I've added to the answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba almost? what does that mean?

Comment: Don't add to this answer - the question is a duplicate. Post an answer on the original question if you feel you can add to its existing answers.